# IF Else or Case Function for SQL select problem

Tags: sql, if-statement, case, teradata

Hi I would like to make a select expression using case or if/else which seems to be a simple solution from logic perspective but I can't seem to get it to work. Basically I am joining against two table here, the first table is customer record with date filter called min_del_date and then the second table for the model scoring table with BIN and update_date parameters.

There are two logics I want to display

1. Picking the model score that was the month before min_del_date
2. If model score month before delivery is greater than 50 (Bin > 50) then pick the model score for same month as min_del_date

My 1st logic code is below

```
with cust as (
    select 
    distinct cust_no, max(del_date) as del_date, min(del_date) as min_del_date, (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM min(del_date)) -1900)*12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM min(del_date))  AS upd_seq
    from customer.cust_history   
    group by 1
)
,model as (
    select party_id, model_id, update_date, upd_seq, bin, var_data8, var_data2
    from 
    (
        select 
        party_id, update_date, bin, var_data8, var_data2,
        (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM UPDATE_DATE) -1900)*12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM UPDATE_DATE) AS upd_seq,
        dense_Rank() over (partition by (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM UPDATE_DATE) -1900)*12 + EXTRACT(MONTH FROM UPDATE_DATE) order by update_date desc) as rank1
        from 
        (
            select party_id,update_date, bin, var_data8, var_data2
            from model.rpm_model
            group by party_id,update_date, bin, var_data8, var_data2
        ) model
    )model_final
    where rank1 = 1
)
-- Add model scores
-- 1st logic Picking the model score that was the month before delivery date
select *
from 
    (
        select cust.cust_no, cust.del_date, cust.min_del_date, model.upd_seq, model.bin
        from cust
        left join cust 
        on cust.cust_no = model.party_id
        and cust.upd_seq = model.upd_seq + 1
    )a
```

Now I am struggling in creating the 2nd logic in the same query?.. any assistance would be appreciated

### cust table

| cust_no | min_del_date | upd_seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-01-11 | 1453 |
| 234 | 2020-06-29 | 1446 |
| 456 | 2020-07-20 | 1447 |

### model table

| party_id | update_date | upd_seq | BIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2020-11-30 | 1451 | 22 |
| 123 | 2020-12-25 | 1452 | 54 |
| 123 | 2020-01-11 | 1453 | 14 |
| 234 | 2020-05-23 | 1445 | 76 |
| 234 | 2020-06-18 | 1446 | 48 |
| 234 | 2020-07-23 | 1447 | 12 |
| 456 | 2020-06-18 | 1446 | 23 |
| 456 | 2020-07-23 | 1447 | 39 |
| 456 | 2020-08-21 | 1448 | 21 |

### desired results

| cust_no | min_del_date | model.upd_seq | update_date | BIN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-01-11 | 1453 | 2020-01-11 | 14 |
| 234 | 2020-06-29 | 1446 | 2020-06-18 | 48 |
| 456 | 2020-07-20 | 1446 | 2020-06-18 | 23 |

**Update**
I managed to find the solution by myself, thanks for everyone who has attending this question. The solution is per below

```
    select a.cust_no, a.del_date, a.min_del_date, b.update_date, b.upd_seq, b.bin
    from 
        (
            select cust.cust_no, cust.del_date, cust.min_del_date, 
            CASE WHEN model.BIN <=50 THEN model.upd_seq WHEN BIN > 50 THEN model.upd_seq +1 ELSE NULL END as upd_seq
            from cust
            inner join model 
            on cust.cust_no = model.party_id
            and cust.upd_seq = model.upd_seq + 1
        )a
    inner join model b 
    on a.cust_no = b.party_id
    and a.upd_seq = b.upd_seq
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help -- as would a tag for the database you are using.

Comment: Hi @GordonLinoff thanks for attending the query. I have added sample data as a table, hopefully you can see it and it make sense. If you look at the desired result, cust 456 would follow the 1st logic of my query nicely where it pick the bin from previous month of the customer update_date model, however for cust 123 and 234 because their Bin score is > 50 for their previous month model, then the query I want is to get the Bin score the same month as cust delivery date. The database I am using is Teradata

Comment: Please, describe your tables and how do they correspond to the text at the beginning? There's no `delivery_date` column in your sample data, and what is the date column in `model` table, that should be *month before* or *the same month*? And what should be done with dates which have no corresponding dates (e same or previous month) in model table? Just imagine you know nothing about your task and describe to yourself what is what in your sample, then correct your question with this explanation.

Comment: Hi @astentx thanks for checking in, I have edited my questions to correspond with the field available in the table and the desired result I want to do is below (please note upd_seq is just date manipulation to combine and extract Year and Month)
IF BIN <= 50 then join cust with model table on cust.cust_no = model.party_id AND cust.upd_seq = model.upd_seq + 1
IF the query above returned BIN score > 50, then pick the BIN for the same month of customer min_del_Date instead (cust.upd_seq = model.upd_seq)